# Как расширить route panel control в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Создал значится карту с функцией прокладки маршрута к заранее определенным точкам.

```
              function contacts_init () {
                  var myContactsMap = new ymaps.Map('contacts_map', {
                          center: [*координаты*, *координаты*],
                          zoom: 13,
                          controls: ['routePanelControl']
                      });
                  var control = myContactsMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');
                  control.options.set({
                      autofocus: false,
                  });
                  control.routePanel.state.set({
                      type: 'masstransit',
                      fromEnabled: true,
                      to: 'Адрес точки B',
                      toEnabled: false
                  });
                  control.routePanel.options.set({
                      allowSwitch: false,
                      reverseGeocoding: true,
                      types: { masstransit: true, pedestrian: true, taxi: true },
                  });
              }
```

И все бы ничего, но окно для ввода адреса отправной точки, тобишь элемент управления route panel control, слишком малое, туда еле помещается название города. Собсна вопрос, как его увеличить?

Порылся в доках, не нашел никаких опций смены внешнего вида панели. Пробовал сделать параметры по подобию других элементов управления, вроде routeButton, не вышло. Гугл тоже не особо дружелюбно отнесся к моей проблеме.

Нужно чтобы оно было процентов на 90 ширины самой карты.Увеличить надо только в ширину.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, нужно добавить параметр в control.options.set, выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
                  control.options.set({
                      autofocus: false,
                      maxWidth: "300px",
                  });
```